# Convert PuTTY key to OpenSSL key?

Tags: ssh

The title says almost everything.

I need to connect to SSH, but on Android I can not find any software which is able to connect with PuTTYs key format.

To convert it to OpenSSH key, every single site recommends Windows and PuTTYgen command which I currently don't have access to.

Uploading the keyfile to some 3rd party server is not suitable for security concerns, so what are my options on Android to convert the PuTTY key to OpenSSL format?

Comment: Where does the Putty key come from? Usually if yo have a Putty key you should also have a Windows machine for converting the key. It is also relevant if the key is in old or new Putty format (there was a key format change about a year ago).

Comment: I generated it on a windows machine which is now died.

Comment: According to a [question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux) there are command line tools for Linux to convert putty keys. May be you can get or compile yourself this tool in Termux app? Not sure if these tool already supports the new key format. Is the key protected with a password? If yes and it is the new key format (file contains something about argon) then you have to check if the converter supports this new format.

Comment: Amaze FileManager seems to support Putty keys for SSH/SCP connections.